# gVim: colorscheme default has no sense in .gvimrc until I write :colo default

Tags: vim, macvim

gVim starts up with a weird theme even though `:colo` returns "default". So I have to manually write `:colo default` to get my preferred colors (specified in `colors/default.vim`).

This is weird! I tried to remove everything from `runtimepath` but no luck.

Comment: Where is `colors/default.vim` located? Is that in your home dir or in `$VIMRUNTIME`? However, I don't think that calling a color scheme "default" will make it the default color scheme. Give it a proper name and set it from `vimrc`.

Comment: Actually in $VIMRUNTIME. How to specify gVim colors in home dir?

Comment: See `:help 'runtimepath'`. You can put your color schemes in `~/.vim/colors/`. Move your `vimrc` to `~/.vim/vimrc` and set the color scheme from there.

Comment: Can we have more info? Is it GVim or the MacVim GUI? what is the full path of that `colors/default.vim`?